# How can I create a gif without losing any image quality

Tags: image, gif, gimp

So I have some pictures that i need to crop and save. 
I crop my images into circles and save them to .gif format so I don't have that white square around my image.
when using GIMP, I just follow the default settings.
my image before it is saved:
[image]

and after it is saved:
[image]

notice the difference in quality. 
I've read on the net that .gif doesn't support as many colors as it should. I tried to follow some advice, but they were directed more towards making animated gifs. I just want to keep the quality.
I have looked at [Poor Quality of the Image after exporting to .gif animation format](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?780449-Poor-Quality-of-the-Image-after-exporting-to-gif-animation-format) and [How can I export a flash file to a gif format without losing quality?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/how-can-i-export-a-flash-file-to-a-gif-format-without-losing-quality), but like I said, they discuss animation.
any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIFs only support up to 256 colours. This is why your quality is degrading. There is no way around this.

> The format supports up to 8 bits per pixel for each image, allowing a
>   single image to reference its own palette of up to 256 different
>   colors chosen from the 24-bit RGB color space.

If all you need is transparency, consider a PNG (Portable Network Graphics) file. It supports a much wider palette and proper partial transparency (alpha channel).

> PNG supports palette-based images (with palettes of 24-bit RGB or
>   32-bit RGBA colors), grayscale images (with or without alpha channel),
>   and full-color non-palette-based RGB[A] images (with or without alpha
>   channel). PNG was designed for transferring images on the Internet,
>   not for professional-quality print graphics, and therefore does not
>   support non-RGB color spaces such as CMYK.

Comment: ok. thx. just saved it and it works. thanks for making this simple